# ng-pattern not working properly, matching every string

Tags: regex, angularjs

I need to validate a password field with pattern matching. I used ng-pattern for that. But it is not working properly.

See [this pluker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/HGkWvltrZpRNeVAoBxsz?p=preview)

The pattern I gave here is, the text should contain at least 8 characters with symbols, alphabets and digits. But when I enter any string the pattern match become true.

See the following code

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="form">
      <input type="text" name="password" ng-model="user.password" ng-pattern="/(^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\W]).*$)/">
      <input type="submit">
      {{form.password.$error}}
    </form>
</body>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should show the code in the question

Comment: I gave a pluker link. It contains the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working. The expression `{{form.password.$error}}` becomes `true` if the field is **invalid**. The empty field does *not* get validated.

So entering `aaaaa` (5 letters) makes the field invalid. Adding `1@` (digit+symbol) is still invalid due to length. Adding anything makes it valid (>= 8 characters with letters, digits, symbols → the display says `false`).

Comment: You mean the regular expression is incorrect doing what the OP describes?

Comment: OP writes: "the text should contain at least 8 characters with symbols, alphabets and digits". So 8 letters is invalid indeed.