# ng-pattern not working with IONCI2

Tags: html, ionic2

I have used: `<input round class="input-container font_style" placeholder="Name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*">` for accepting alphabets and numeric only but currently its accepting other languages, emojis, special characters and all others too. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-pattern not working properly, matching every string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216170/ng-pattern-not-working-properly-matching-every-string)